# python flask microframework not able to use session variable

Tags: python-2.7, session, curl, flask, sqlalchemy

```
from flask import Flask,redirect
from flask import session
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.route('/signup', methods = ['POST'])
def signup():
    email = 'xxxx'
    session['email'] = email
    print session['email']
    print("The email address is '" + email + "'")
    return redirect('/')

@app.route('/unregister', methods = ['POST'])
def unregister():
    print "session check"
    print session['email']
    return 'We have removed  from the list!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = '#d\xe9X\x00\xbe~Uq\xebX\xae\x81\x1fs\t\xb4\x99\xa3\x87\xe6.\xd1_'
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

When I run this I am able to run a server on http://127.0.0.1:5000/. The problem I am facing is that I am able to use `session` in `signup` but not able to use it in `unregister`. I am using it through curl:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/unregister
```

I see this error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Apr/2016 16:06:08] "POST /unregister HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ,   
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1820, in
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1403, in
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/pvelumul/ACI/workspace/acitoolkit/applications/snapback/helloworld.py", line 20, in unregister
    print session['email']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.11.4-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/local.py", line 373, in <lambda>
    __getitem__ = lambda x, i: x._get_current_object()[i]
KeyError: 'email'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a salient part:

When you assign a session variable, like this: `session['email'] = email`, Flask saves that info in the browser's cookie. Hence, it can only be read through the browser.

You are trying to read the session using a cURL POST request. But, the command line is different from the browser, which means cURL cannot has no access to the browser.

That way, reading `session['email']` will return a `KeyError` which means, `email` is not present.

The proper way to read a session variable is when running the app in the browser, not through a command line request.

Also, you should use `session.get('email')` which returns `None` if the key is not present, rather than throw an error.

> The problem I am facing is that I am able to use session in signup but not able to use it in unregister

When you visit `/signup` from the command line, you are only assigning to the session object in memory, which is no longer available after the code has finished running.